# amp CLIENT_ID substitution in anchor tag

Tags: amp-html

According to the [spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md) I should be able to use the CLIENT_ID variable in my anchor hrefs. On my amp page, I have an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/link-to-non-amp-page/?var=testing&clientID=CLIENT_ID(google-analytics)" target="_blank">test link</a>
```

Going by the spec, I expect amp to substitute the CLIENT_ID variable with the actual value when I click the link. However, when I go to link-to-non-amp-page, the CLIENT_ID in the query string is not updated. I tried searching through the spec and the amphtml source but couldn't find any information that could help me.

Am I misinterpreting what the amp spec says I can do with variable substitutions? Is there a way to get the CLIENT_ID on an anchor href?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

variable substitutions only work on amp-pixel and amp-analytics for now. There is an effort to expose this to all URLs but it is not avilable everywhere yet.

You can track the progress at https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4078

If you would like to test this before it is released, you can go to https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html and enable the experiment called: `link-url-replace`